# creating a bar chart using Highcharts with React - getting an error that rendering div isn't found

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to create a bar chart with Highcharts in my web application, which uses React on the front end. Below is a snippet of my dashboard.tsx file, where I basically just copied and pasted the code from a JSFiddle 
(http://jsfiddle.net/8qjcz4q0/)
that renders a simple bar chart with Highcharts, but for some reason it's not working and I get an error in my console (Highcharts error #13) that the rendering div isn't showing.

```
 import * as React from "react";
 import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
 import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";

 Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
    type: 'column'
   },
  title: {
    text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
   },
 subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: Wikipedia'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
      }
   },
   yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Population (millions)'
    }
   },
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
},
series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: [
        ['Shanghai', 23.7],
        ['Lagos', 16.1],
        ['Istanbul', 14.2],
        ['Karachi', 14.0],
        ['Mumbai', 12.5],
        ['Moscow', 12.1],
        ['São Paulo', 11.8],
        ['Beijing', 11.7],
        ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
        ['Delhi', 11.1],
        ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
        ['Seoul', 10.4],
        ['Jakarta', 10.0],
        ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
        ['Tianjin', 9.3],
        ['Tokyo', 9.0],
        ['Cairo', 8.9],
        ['Dhaka', 8.9],
        ['Mexico City', 8.9],
        ['Lima', 8.9]
    ],

 }]
});
render() {
     return ( <div>
        <div id="container"></div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My suspicion is that the HTML id attribute doesn't work with React, but I don't know if Highcharts can render to class instead of id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question here, the render function is called after highcharts attempts to look for the div. You can put the chart rendering code in the componentDidMount() section, render the highcharts code directly using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, or set a timer on the highcharts code.
To the other answer, the problem with sticking the div tag in my html is that I'm rendering everything else in the JSX and thus want to render my chart from inside my JSX.

Answer (score 0):

[JS bin](http://jsbin.com/xohunaseri/1/edit?html,js,output) demo

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-highcharts/11.0.0/ReactHighcharts.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React-highcharts</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Part

```
var config = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
            ['Shanghai', 23.7],
            ['Lagos', 16.1],
            ['Istanbul', 14.2],
            ['Karachi', 14.0],
            ['Mumbai', 12.5],
            ['Moscow', 12.1],
            ['São Paulo', 11.8],
            ['Beijing', 11.7],
            ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
            ['Delhi', 11.1],
            ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
            ['Seoul', 10.4],
            ['Jakarta', 10.0],
            ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
            ['Tianjin', 9.3],
            ['Tokyo', 9.0],
            ['Cairo', 8.9],
            ['Dhaka', 8.9],
            ['Mexico City', 8.9],
            ['Lima', 8.9]
        ],

    }]
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactHighcharts config = {config}/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```